# From $1,2, \cdots ,9$ pick $5$ numbers so that the sum is $22$. Do the same so that the sum is $28$. Which one has more ways of addition?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> From $1,2, \cdots ,9$ pick $5$ numbers so that the sum is $22$. Do the same so that the sum is $28$. Which one has more ways of combination? $22$ or $28$?

I couldn't figure out a combinatorial way to do this. Even with enumerating, there is still risk of not getting all of them. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not write a c program it will take only 9000 iterations?

Comment: Haha this is a GRE problem so might not be able to write code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5\}$ is a subset of $\{1,2,3, \dots, 9\}$ with sum $S$.  Then $\{10-x_1, 10-x_2, 10-x_3, 10-x_4, 10-x_5\}$ is also a subset of  $\{1,2,3, \dots, 9\}$, but with sum $50-S$.  So there is a one-to-one correspondence between subsets with sum $S$ and subsets with sum $50-S$.

In particular, there are exactly as many subsets with sum $22$ as subsets with sum $28$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the average result when adding $5$ numbers? Then there is symmetry you can use.

Comment: Hi thank you very much! Could you be more specific? What you mean by average result?

Answer (score 0):

So let's us start with the range of numbers which is (5-45)the number of combinations increases from (5-25) then starts decreasing from (25-45). So the maximum number of combinations is possible for 25 and no of combinations are symmetrical around it hence the distance form 25 determines which has more combinations.

Comment: Hi I forgot to say that we should pick the numbers without replacement. Not sure if this affects your result?

Comment: @stevengerrard yes because same applies to all.

Comment: @stevengerrard it's similar to the total of two dice problem and it's probability distribution check it out.